# Calling genericallytyped methods with constraints from Methods without constraints

Tags: c#, generics

Is it possible to cast generic types so you can call Generically typed methods with constraints from Methods without the same constraints. (as per the below code)

```
private static void CheckThenCall<T>()
{
    if(typeof(IHaveInterface).IsAssignableFrom(T))
    {
        Call<T>();
    }
}
private static void Call<T>() where T : IHaveInterface
{
    var typeOf = typeof(T);
}
```

Comment: Is there a point to using generics methods if you're gonna do 'typeof dancing' inside them. Consider putting Call<T> in the interface & making IHaveInterface<T>

Comment: I'm not really sure this makes any sense. What is the point of having generic methods that take no arguments and return void? The generic type parameter is completely useless in this scenario. Maybe you should write up a better example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presumably you will be wanting to use objects of type T, rather than just the type itself?

If so, then it's easy using the [as operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cscsdfbt.aspx), the [is operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/scekt9xw.aspx) and [GetType](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.object.gettype.aspx). All of these work at run-time, using the actual type of the object.

Unfortunately `is` and `as` do not work on value types, so you would need to restrict T to classes only.

```
private static void CheckThenCall<T>(T param) where T : class
{
    if (param is IHaveInterface)
    {
        Call(param as IHaveInterface);
    }
}

private static void Call<T>(T param) where T : IHaveInterface
{
    Type typeOf = param.GetType();
}
```

Comment: Just a quick note: there's no point doing `is` and then doing `as`. Doing `is` does the cast, and then `as` does it again. Do `as` in the first place and then check it for null. Also - in other situations don't do `as` without checking the result for null; just do a hard cast. That way you'll get an InvalidCastException instead of a NullReferenceException if it doesn't work.

Comment: Well I guess the point would be to Call<T> some times, but not others :-)

Comment: @RichardIrons - That's not a good idea to intentionally allow the code to throw an exception. Exceptions should be exceptional.

Comment: Well, as I said, you should do `as` and then check for null. If you have `as` (not guarded by an `is` statement like this code) and it isn't followed by a check for null, then you are already risking an exception. By hard casting instead of `as`, then at least it will be a useful exception. It doesn't mean you're using an exception as branching. The rule is, do ONE cast. Use `is` if you only need to know whether it is one. Use `as` if you're going to check for null. And use a hard cast if your code is assuming the cast will work (so that, if it doesn't work, it will indeed be "exceptional").

Comment: The answer is just a demo, introducing the `is` and `as` operators.

Answer (score 0):

Generic constraints are checked at compile time, so by run time it is too late! So in short, no

Answer (score 0):

You can't, because it's checked at compile time. However, you can modify your code slightly to make it. Let's say we have two interfaces:

```
interface IFoo1 { }
interface IFoo2 { }
```

And you have two generic methods with constraints:

```
static void Foo1<T>() where T : IFoo1
{
    var t = typeof(T);  
}

static void Foo2<T>() where T : IFoo2
{
    var t = typeof(T);
}
```

I'm 100% sure you care about `typeof(T)` in Foo1 and Foo2, because besides the two there is nothing important. And you have another generic method which has no constraints:

```
static void Foo<T>(T instance)
{
    if (instance is IFoo1)
    {
        Foo1<T>();  //compile error!
    }
}
```

If you pass the instance, things will be easier:

```
static void Foo<T>(T instance)
{
    if (instance is IFoo1)
    {
        Foo1(instance as IFoo1);
    }
}

static void Foo1<T>(T instance) where T : IFoo1
{
    var t = instance.GetType();
}

static void Foo2<T>(T instance) where T : IFoo2
{
    var t = instance.GetType();
}
```